# Android streams average from a map

Tags: android, dictionary, lambda, java-stream, average

I have a list of objects

```
class Result {
    private String name;
    private Map<String, Double> map;

    // getters, constructor etc
}
```

I want to group it by a name, and make average of double values in a map for each key. Each object in a list have the map with the same keys.

I started by grouping by name

```
Map <String, List<Result>> grouppedByName = Stream.of(results)
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Result::getName));
```

I don't know what next apart of regular loop.

Example data:

```
INPUT:

name = "Name 1"
map:
KEY1, 10
KEY2, 1

name = "Name 1"
map:
KEY1, 20
KEY2, 7

name = "Name 2"
map:
KEY1, 2
KEY2, 3
--------------
OUTPUT:

name = "Name 1"
map:
KEY1, 15                           (10+20)/2 = 15
KEY2, 4                            (1+7)/2 = 4

name = "Name 2"
map:
KEY1, 2
KEY2, 3
```

Comment: you should be more specific, show your input, and show expected output

Comment: I added an example data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `groupingBy` method will produce `Map<String, List<Result>>`. We need a method to transform the `List<Result>` values of this map to something more useful:

```
Map<String, Double> mapMerger(final List<Result> results) {
    return results.stream()
            .map(Result::getMap)
            .map(Map::entrySet)
            .flatMap(Set::stream)
            .collect(groupingBy(Entry::getKey, averagingDouble(Entry::getValue)));
}
```

This will extract all entries of type `Entry<String, Double>` from all the maps in all results. It will aggregate these entries into a map from each key to the average of all values for that key.

We can apply this new method by creating a stream from the original map (`grouppedByName` in your question):

```
Map<String, Map<String, Double>> averagedByName = results.stream()
        .collect(groupingBy(Result::getName))
        .entrySet().stream()
        .collect(toMap(Entry::getKey, e -> mapMerger(e.getValue())));
```

The you should get `15` if you do:

```
double avg = averagedByName.get("Name 1").get("KEY1");
```